# Inside Constructor what is the use of inject decorator

Tags: angular

When I'm reading the blog about dynamic component creation, I have seen the below inject decorator inside the `constructor`.

```
constructor(@Inject(ComponentFactoryResolver) factoryResolver) {
    this.factoryResolver = factoryResolver
}
```

Why we are injecting like this? Can any one please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that angular will handle automatically and internally the instance creation for the factoryResolver.

In latest versions of angular you don't need to specify the @Inject in the constructor, nor the assign to this.factoryResolver:

`constructor (private factoryResover: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}`

You can read more about angular dependency injection here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: then why material using inject decorator constructor(@Inject(MAT_KEYBOARD_DEADKEYS) private _deadkeys: IKeyboardDeadkeys,
@Inject(MAT_KEYBOARD_ICONS) private _icons: IKeyboardIcons) { }

Comment: It is the same, see api docs for Inject: https://angular.io/api/core/Inject